# Background service not working App crashes in android 8.0.1

Tags: broadcast, android-8.0-oreo, background-service, android-jobscheduler

### This is my receiver class

public class LocationAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "LocationAlarmReceiver";

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (AppClass.networkConnectivity.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            if (AppClass.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                  context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, UpdateLatLngBackgroundService.class));
                } else {
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateLatLngBackgroundService.class));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: 
Exception is coming

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting a background service as by using startForegroundService

it will be consider as a Foreground service. For Foreground service you have to create a notification to  display. [see for more detiails](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

And while creating notification from oreo(8.0) onwards you have to create a channel and register with NotificationManager. [More details how to create notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you added attribute -> name=".the name of the class that you created channels in"

inside tag in manifest file.